# Unable to formulate the correct formulation for maximize a function

Tags: maximum

So, i want to express these:

$$\max(\cos(x)\cos(y)\cos(z)),\quad x+y+z=\pi,\quad x,y,z\in(0,\pi]$$

Attempt:

```
In[81]:= NMaximize[{Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[z], 
  x + y + z == Pi && 0 < x <= \[Pi] && 0 < y <= \[Pi] && 
   0 < z <= \[Pi]}, {x, y, z}]

Out[81]= {0.125, {x -> 1.0472, y -> 1.0472, z -> 1.0472}}
```

But how so? I tried manually like this:

```
In[82]:= N[Cos[30 Degree] Cos[30 Degree] Cos[30 Degree]]

Out[82]= 0.649519
```

The above calculation implies there are numbers greater than the maximum value, i mean $0.649>0.125$. I think, i made a mistake to formulate the expression. Could you help me please? If the formulation is correct that would be greater or equal to `Out[82]`. Thanks in advance?

Comment: x = y = z = 30 Degree doesn't satisfy your constraint x + y + z = 180 Degree. I believe your code does produce the correct maximum, given your constraint.

Comment: Drawing a picture can help with confidence about an answer: `ContourPlot[Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[\[Pi] - x - y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi] - x}, Contours -> Range[-12, 12]/100., PlotPoints -> 100]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Maximize` or `ArgMax` or `MaxValue` to confirm your result.

```
Maximize[{Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[z], 
  x + y + z == Pi && 0 < x <= π && 0 < y <= π && 
   0 < z <= π}, {x, y, z}]
```

> `{1/8, {x -> π/3, y -> π/3, z -> π/3}}`

```
ArgMax[{Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[z], 
  x + y + z == Pi && 0 < x <= π && 0 < y <= π && 
   0 < z <= π}, {x, y, z}]
```

> `{π/3, π/3, π/3}`

```
MaxValue[{Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[z], 
  x + y + z == Pi && 0 < x <= π && 0 < y <= π && 
   0 < z <= π}, {x, y, z}]
```

> `1/8`